# Cell Reference in a QUERY statement not working

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I'm trying to add a cell reference (on the same sheet where the QUERY function is at) to a QUERY function

On B1 there is this value: 13/09/2019

QUERY function:

```
=QUERY(FORMULARIO!A1:S, "SELECT G WHERE Q contains '13/09/2019'")
```

I tried doing this but didnt work:

```
=QUERY(FORMULARIO!A1:S, "SELECT G WHERE Q contains '"&B2&"'")
```

I cant use a FILTER function here because I'm grabbing selected columns from the master sheet and changing the original order and FILTER doesn't allow that

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the data type of the value on B2? Is it a date or a text value?

Comment: Good question by @Rubén. Please share a link to a test sheet. It would be great help.

Comment: Can I get an example of the spreadsheet that you are using?

Answer (score 1):

When dealing with dates in Google Sheets Query function, dates should be in a certain format.
They need to be  as a string literal in the format **`yyyy-mm-dd`**, otherwise it can’t perform the comparison filter.

### Query function needs dates in **`yyyy-mm-dd`** format

In your case your formula should read `2019-09-13`
**`=QUERY(FORMULARIO!A1:S, "SELECT G WHERE Q contains '2019-09-13'")`**

Comment: What if he uses the date-serial instead? I.e. 9/13/2019 = 43721